# Planting new between established cedars (emerald)?

Tags: cedar

I moved house and the garden has a row of cedars that are about 6-7ft tall and have been there for approx 10 years (looking at old satellite photos). The are planted with gaps between the trees that I would like to fill. The gap varies across the row, but many of them I can easily step through to the other side. Can I plant new cedars in the gap to create more of a hedge or will it kill the established ones? Or is there an alternative that i can plant that will add height? I would like privacy without having to fence.

Thank you.

Comment: HI, welcome! It's common practice here to post a few pictures so that your problems can be addressed with more confidence. Also, additional information may be needed, such as: your climate zone, your soil type, budget constraints etc.. Basically, anything you can think of that might help people address your question.

Comment: Thanks, i will get a picture and add it and add more info.